# Same RAM model, different purchase date. Will this work?

Tags: memory, compatibility, ddr3

I went for a triple channel (3x2GB) DDR3 RAM kit for my build back in 2010.
The same kit is now a lot cheaper and I'm considering purchasing one to give my machine a little boost.

Relevant Specs:

- RAM: [Corsair XMS3 3x2GB DDR3 1600MHz TR3X6G1600C9](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Corsair-TR3X6G1600C9-1600MHz-9-9-9-24-motherboards/dp/B001K56XW8)
- Motherboard: [ASUS P6X58D-E](http://uk.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/P6X58DE/)
- Intel Core i7-930
- Windows 7 (x64)
- No overclocking

Is it wise to mix newly manufactured RAM? Would I have problems?
Maybe it's better to buy two of the kits now *(still cheaper than when I bought one 2 years ago)* and replace what I already have (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar and can speak from personal experience.

About 6 months ago I purchased the exact same RAM kit (2x2GB) that I purchased about 2 years ago.

It has not complained in 6 months and there is no reason that it should.

Mixing the same RAM from different dates shouldn't worry you but mixing different types/brands could cause problems.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks, @harper89. That's given me some confidence. I think it's worth a go!...

Answer (score 1):

> 6 x DIMM, Max. 24GB, DDR3 2000(O.C.)/1600/1333/1066 Hz Non-ECC,
>   Un-buffered Memory Triple Channel Memory Architecture

I think you're good purchasing 1 kit to add to your current kit. No reason to purchase two when the max is 6 sticks.

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian. Sorry - I meant take out what I have and purchase 2 at the same time. I'd probably chuck the old one in a drawer or sell it.